# ¿Por que cuando exporto un proyecto de Unity 2d a android y lo ejecuto en mi celular solo aparece una pantalla azul?

Tags: c#, android, unity, unity2d, exportar

realmente soy nuevo en Unity y en el lenguaje de C# y no se por que pasa eso, según los tutoriales estoy bien pero no funciona, por el momento en el programa es un simple menú con una imagen y un canva que contiene un texto y un botón pero cuando lo ejecuto en mi celular solo aparece un color azul que ni siquiera es el color de que le indique a la cámara.
Como dije soy nuevo en esto y si requieren algo mas de información para que me ayuden estaré dispuesto a proporcionarla.
Gracias :)